# How to use `tf.data.Dataset` in Tensorflow V2 with graphs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I spot that functions, such as `make_one_shot_iterator`, have been deprecated in Tensorflow V2, and the suggestion is to use `for ... in dataset`, which requires eager execution enabled. I'm confused that without
these functions, how can we extract data from `Dataset` with graphs? It seems to me now that the only choice is to turn to `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)`. Are there any suggested choice in V2? Why would these functions be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official documentation, Datasets will become iterables in TF 2.0 and eager mode will be enabled bu default. You can find more about it here
 https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/guide/effective_tf2.md

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using TF 1.13 and according to the instruction you provide, it seems that I still have to make do with `make_one_shot_iterator`.